# Why do we use the t-distribution for this problem? Isn't the sample size too large?

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

I always thought t-distributions were used instead of normal distributions when the standard error estimate was bad and when samples were small. Here's a quote from OpenIntro Statistics:

> So what should we do when the sample size is small? As we’ll discuss
>   in Section 5.1.1, if the population data are nearly normal, then ...
>   The accuracy of the standard error is trickier, and for this challenge
>   we’ll introduce a new distribution called the t-distribution. While we
>   emphasize the use of the t-distribution for small samples, this
>   distribution is also generally used for large samples, where it
>   produces similar results to those from the normal distribution.
>
> In the cases where we will use a small sample to calculate the
>   standard error, it will be useful to rely on a new distribution for
>   inference calculations: the t-distribution. A t- distribution, shown
>   as a solid line in Figure 5.1, has a bell shape. However, its tails
>   are thicker than the normal model’s. This means observations are more
>   likely to fall beyond two standard deviations from the mean than under
>   the normal distribution.1 While our estimate of the standard error
>   will be a little less accurate when we are analyzing a small data set,
>   these extra thick tails of the t-distribution are exactly the
>   correction we need to resolve the problem of a poorly estimated
>   standard error.

I'm reading an intro to stats book and this is the question that I find confusing:

> Are textbooks actually cheaper online? Here we compare the price of textbooks at the University of California, Los Angeles’ (UCLA’s) bookstore and prices at Amazon.com. Seventy-three UCLA courses were randomly sampled in Spring 2010, representing less than 10% of all UCLA courses. A portion of the data set is shown in Table 5.9:

[image]

This is the quote that I find confusing:

> Can the t-distribution be used for this application? The observations are based on a simple random sample from less than 10% of all books sold at the bookstore, so independence is reasonable. While the distribution is strongly skewed, the sample is reasonably large (n = 73), so we can proceed. Because the conditions are reasonably satisfied, we can apply the t-distribution to this setting.

Why are we applying the t distribution when the sample is large? I thought we were supposed to use the t-distribution when the sample is small.

What does it mean for the standard error to be less accurate?

Perhaps I misunderstood... are the t distribution and normal distributions mutually exclusive? Or are they two sides of the same coin?

Comment: It should be mentioned that the reasoning behind them using the relatively large sample size to justify the t-test even though the parent distribution is highly skewed is that the sample mean's distribution will not be very skewed due to the central limit theorem. However, it's unclear to me how one can jump from that conclusion to that it's t-distributed. Using t instead of z only corrects for the finite sample size, not the effect of skew and kurtosis of the parent distribution. (I guess the assumption is we're at a happy medium sample size where the first matters and the second doesn't.)

Comment: More precisely, instead of 'Using t instead of z only corrects for the finite sample size' I should say 'corrects for the estimation error of the variance'... they're all finite sample size effects that will go away when $n$ gets large enough, it's just a question of their relative importance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically , you will hear that the $t$-test should be used when the sample size is small such as $n<30$, but with a large sample size, you use the $Z$-test.

However, there is nothing wrong with using a $t$-test with a large sample size. When the sample size is large enough, the $t$- and $Z$- tests will produce very similar results, which is why people will rely on the $Z$ approximation. But if anything, the $t$-test may still even be accurate.

If you are using a table, it may be hard to use the $t$-test when there is a large sample, because the table may not list the appropriate degrees of freedom. Like in your example, you wouldn't usually find $72$ df on a standard $t$-table.  However, if you are using software, performing the $t$-test should not be a problem.

As far as the standard error being less accurate, this is because we are trying to use the standard error of the sample to estimate the standard error of the population.  The smaller the sample is, the less confident we are that the sample standard error closely approximates the true standard deviation.

Comment: The last sentence I find confusing. If the sample number gets bigger... doesn't the SE just get smaller? Isn't the SE formula just $\frac{\sigma^2}{\sqrt{n}}$ If it just gets smaller (and not necessarily closer to $\sigma^2$), how can we say that it just gets more accurate?

Comment: So you're saying that choosing between the t and z distributions seems like not a one or the other scenario? The z distribution sounds more like this platonic ideal of distributions whereas the t distribution seems more accurate and adjusts to the errors of the SE?

Comment: When the sample gets bigger, the SE of the **sample mean** gets smaller.  But the SE of the sample itself doesn't necessarily get bigger or smaller.  However, it is more likely to closely approximate the population SE, the same way that a sample mean of a large sample is a better approximation of a population mean than that of a small sample.

Comment: So the SE is used to describe both the standard deviation of the sampling distribution/sample mean (several samples and their subsequent means) AND the standard deviation of the single sample?

Comment: Correct, the z-distribution is simpler and perhaps easier to use, therefore we use when it is accurate enough.

Comment: When we use a formula such as ${s^2\over \sqrt n}$, $s$ refers to the SE that we derived from the single sample, while the entire formula is used to approximate the SE of the sample mean (with a sample of size $n$).

Comment: I think you might have incorrectly said SE in a few places when you meant SD. Is that right? For example, I think this sentence should be SD: "But the SD of the sample itself doesn't necessarily get bigger or smaller. However, it is more likely to closely approximate the population SD, "

Comment: You are correct, I should have been more accurate in my terminology. The SD of a larger sample is a better approximation for the population SD, which in turn makes the SE of the sample mean more accurate.